# VS 2010 Connecting to SQL Server 2008: Login failed for user "

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I've created a web forms project in Visual studio 2010 that has to connect to an SQL Server 2008 database that's located on a different computer on the local network.

Here's my connection string from the web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDatabase"
         connectionString="Data Source=myDatabase;Initial Catalog=myCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword*"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here's the string used in my entlib.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataConfiguration"
                 type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="myDatabase" />
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myDatabase"
             connectionString="Data Source=myDataBase;Initial Catalog=myCatalog;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The problem I'm encountering changes based on what's in entlib.config.  If

```
Integrated Security=true;
```

is in the connection string the error I get is

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

And if the integrated security tag is removed I get

> Login failed for user ''.

I don't know why this isn't working because my company has other web projects that are able to connect to this database and I'm using the same exact connection code. The user name and passwords work when I log into SQL Management Studio. I can see the database in VS 2010's server explorer, and I'm using the connection string from there.  I'm passing SQL Server authentication, and I know the right server is being reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying the entire `connectionString` value from web.config to entlib.config

Comment: Well, it worked.  This is kind of embarassing.  But now I'm wondering why the other projects don't have the same connection strings in those two config files, and yet they work.  Either way, thanks a lot.